# Execute multiple queries in single query using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two queries. One is gross sale and other is net sale. I want to report in a single query. How can I do that?

Gross Sale

```
Location Name                                     Gsale 
(sub-dealer-temp)                                   2   
2049 (Sub-Dealer) Always Protected, LLC             3   
2052 (Sub-Dealer) Alert Security, Inc               4   
2055 (Sub-Dealer) Alarm Connection, LLC             5   
2067 (Sub-Dealer-t) Activation Dept, LLC            67  
2068 (Sub-Dealer-t) Premier Security USA, LLC       8
```

Net Sale

```
location Name                                     Nsale 
2055 (Sub-Dealer) Alarm Connection, LLC             5   
2067 (Sub-Dealer-t) Activation Dept, LLC           67   
2068 (Sub-Dealer-t) Premier Security USA, LLC       8   
2783 ((Sub-Dealer-t) Premier abc                    45  
2783 ((Sub-Dealer-t) Premier xyz                    32
```

Result

```
Lc.Name                                Gsale             Nsale
(sub-dealer-temp)                        2               null
2049 (Sub-Dealer) Always Protected, LLC  3               null
2052 (Sub-Dealer) Alert Security, Inc    4               null
2055 (Sub-Dealer) Alarm Connection, LLC  5                5
2067 (Sub-Dealer-t) Activation Dept, LLC 67               67
2068 (Sub-Dealer-t) Premier Security US  8                8
2783 ((Sub-Dealer-t) Premier abc        null              45
2783 ((Sub-Dealer-t) Premier xyz        null              32
```

Comment: **Hint**: `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

you can use a join or union below is the join query

```
     select g.location,g.name,g.Gsale,n.Nsale from gross sale g 
     join net sale n on g.location=n.location
```

Comment: please learn to format a vertical block. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow sql code:

Table name 1 : Gross Sale is now `gross_sale` and column name `lcName`, `Gsale`

Table name 2 : Net Sale is now `net_sale` and column name `lcName`, `Nsale`

```
SELECT a.lcName, a.Gsale, b.Nsale FROM gross_sale a 
FULL OUTER JOIN net_sale b ON a.lcName=b.lcName ORDER BY a.lcName;
```

Comment: you want a full outer join not a left join right? See the column `Gsale`?

Comment: @Drew can you explain clearly?

Comment: What does a left join do?

Comment: @Drew Sorry for that, yes it will FULL OUTER JOIN.